# Creating a write stream to download an audio stream without Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use ytdl-core in the browser to download an mp3. I got ytdl-core to work in the browser without Node.js, but I am having some trouble with saving the stream as a file. It looks like generally, you would have a client/server doing this together but I was wondering if it could all be done client-side.

This is the part that I don't know how to recreate using pure JS.

```js
fs.createWriteStream('video.flv')
```

This is the object that I am trying to download as an mp3:

```
PassThrough {_readableState: ReadableState, readable: true, _events: {…}, _eventsCount: 2, _maxListeners: undefined, …}
allowHalfOpen: true
destroy: () => { stream._isDestroyed = true; }
readable: true
writable: true
_events: {end: ƒ, prefinish: ƒ}
_eventsCount: 2
_maxListeners: undefined
_readableState: ReadableState {objectMode: false, highWaterMark: 524288, buffer: BufferList, length: 0, pipes: null, …}
_transformState: {needTransform: false, transforming: false, writecb: null, writechunk: null, afterTransform: ƒ, …}
_writableState: WritableState {objectMode: false, highWaterMark: 524288, finalCalled: false, needDrain: false, ending: false, …}
destroyed: (...)
readableHighWaterMark: (...)
writableHighWaterMark: (...)
__proto__: Transform
```

This is the example given by ytdl-core using Node.js.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
// TypeScript: import ytdl from 'ytdl-core'; with --esModuleInterop
// TypeScript: import * as ytdl from 'ytdl-core'; with --allowSyntheticDefaultImports
// TypeScript: import ytdl = require('ytdl-core'); with neither of the above
 
ytdl('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A02s8omM_hI')
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('video.flv'));
```

So my question is, is there a way to save the file stream in pure JS and then download the file all in browser?

Answer (score 0):

For

```
"This is the part that I don't know how to recreate using pure JS.

fs.createWriteStream('video.flv')
```

Please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API

Might help.

This is a part from the MDN page,

```
Streaming involves breaking a resource that you want to receive over a network down 
into small chunks, then processing it bit by bit. This is something browsers do anyway 
when receiving assets to be shown on webpages — videos buffer and more is gradually 
available to play, and sometimes you'll see images display gradually as more is 
loaded.

But this has never been available to JavaScript before. Previously, if we wanted to 
process a resource of some kind (be it a video, or a text file, etc.), we'd have to 
download the entire file, wait for it to be deserialized into a suitable format, then 
process the whole lot after it is fully received.

With Streams being available to JavaScript, this all changes — you can now start 
processing raw data with JavaScript bit by bit as soon as it is available on the 
client-side, without needing to generate a buffer, string, or blob.
```

Comment: I was looking into this, but the lack of browser support is a bit worrying. For now if I wanted to try this, do you know how I could go about saving the Writeable stream to a file? All the information I can gather online uses Node.js and I'm really trying to stick to pure JS.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams. Check this link. Might need to create a blob . There is an example shown for a image.